# How to subscribe to Application.ApplicationExit from library assembly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a way to subscribe to this event or something similar so I can perform some clean up codes before objects are finalized?

Comment: Same way you subscribe to any event. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Not from the main form assembly but from dll?

Comment: Yes? And what seems to be the problem? It is a static event.

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms assembly then

Answer (score 3):

The event is static so using it in a DLL doesn't cause any problem.

Do beware however that the event is only fired if your class library is actually used from a Winforms application.  You can only be sure of that if you expose functionality that is only usable from a Winforms app.  Like a custom control or UserControl.

Alternatives are the AppDomain events, DomainUnload and ProcessExit.  Or just expecting the main app to let you know about the shutdown.  Which is usually the better choice, you don't necessarily *know* why the app is exiting.  You wouldn't want to save settings on a hard crash for example.  Note how the ApplicationSettingsBase class follows that pattern as well, you have to explicitly call its Save() method.

Answer (score 1):

You subscribe to this event in the same manner you would with *any* event.

The example on the [ApplicationExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx) MSDN page is clear:

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);

private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // do your cleanups
}
```